# Enabling a console for a Ruby app

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I'm trying to add a console to my Ruby cli application (much like the Rails console), but I can't seem to find a solution that does what I need:

- Colorization & syntax highlighting
- Ability to pass in variables or use the current context

I'd like to use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), but I can't figure out how to disable the code context from being printed out at the start of the session. I'd like it to immediately start the session without printing anything out besides the prompt.

Here's what currently gets printed when the pry session starts:

```
Frame number: 0/8

From: <file_path> @ line <#> <Class>#<method>:

    71: def console
    72:   client_setup
    73:   puts "Console Connected to #{@client.url}"
    74:   puts 'HINT: The @client object is available to you'
    75: rescue StandardError => e
    76:   puts "WARNING: Couldn't connect to #{@client.url}"
    77: ensure
    78:   Pry.config.prompt = proc { "> " }
    79:   binding.pry
 => 80: end
>
```

Here's what I want:

```
>
```

I've also tried a few other solutions, but here's my problems with each:

- IRB: No colorization, doesn't seem customizable
- [ripl](https://github.com/cldwalker/ripl): No colorization or syntax highlighting

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make your program load Pry, but I think the correct solution is to make Pry load your program. Put the code you want to run before the Pry prompt appears in a file called, say, `setup.rb`. Then start Pry with `pry -r setup.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is defining a pretty simple/empty class to bind to:

```
class Console
  def initialize(client)
    @client = client
  end
end
```

Then in my console method:

```
Pry.config.prompt = proc { '> ' }
Pry.plugins['stack_explorer'] && Pry.plugins['stack_explorer'].disable!
Pry.start(Console.new(@client))
```

Disabling the stack_explorer prevented it from printing the Frame number info, and inside the Pry session, I can access @client as expected.

Answer (score 1):

We usually create a separate executable file like bin/console in our project and put there content similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative "../application"

require "pry"
Pry.start
```

Where application.rb is a file which loads gems via Bundler and includes all necessary application-related files, so it will be possible to use application classes in the console.

It's easy to start your console with just ./bin/console command from your terminal.

If you need to customise the look of console then official wiki at github has enough information about this: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration

Comment: Thanks @SunnyMagadan. I'm actually doing this all within a Thor cli already, and there's some setup code that I'd like to be able to utilize and share for other cli commands. The main thing I'm looking for is what option to set to disable the code from being printed prior to starting the session. I couldn't find that in the wiki.

Comment: ...that or if I can figure out how to create a new empty binding and place a variable in it, that would be great too.